# How to combine large scale and small scale in one project

Tags: scale

I want to animate a space scene of stations and ships in the orbit of Mars.

I thought about two ways to do this:

- **Planet as a rendered picture on the World texture**
  I cannot make this to work as the picture is deformed - not suitable for a proper skybox. I tried texture mapping.
- **Actual Planet as a large (cubic) sphere**
  Either the mesh become too large (artifacts on surface when zooming out) or the planet still looks too small.
  I will also try to move the Planet together with the camera to make it look static/large by connecting the coords. Have just to pay attention to shadows and mesh "collision".

Are there any general ideas on how to approach? I will post pictures or even the scene later on today.

I am quite inexperienced. Using blender 2.9+
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want Mars to be a static background, you could create a HDRI image as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/a48PBPRO8O8) video. You basically render a equirectangular version of your scene and use it as the background in your second scene. Note that you have to switch to Cycles, a step not mentioned in the video.

Comment: I think this is exactly solving my issue. Did not know about that feature, opening a new world to me . Thank you. Will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could work with some kind of Level-of-Detail approach?
Model the spaceships and the full planet as a sphere with displacement map in one scene, then a section of the planet with some geometry detail and low-detail structures and finally a small patch of terrain with structures with high detail.
Then render separately and blend between the detail levels in post processing?

If you match the colors and contours just well enough and make the transition either very quickly or very smoothly, hardly anybody will notive the transition